# Can $\sigma(n)-n$ be a proper divisor of $n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisor-sum

Let $n\ge 2$ be a natural number, $\sigma(n)$ the sum of its divisors.

- Can $\sigma(n)-n$ be a PROPER divisor of $n$ ?

If $\sigma(n)-n=n$ , $n$ is a perfect number.

If $\sigma(n)-n=1$ , $n$ is a prime number.

I checked the numbers upto $n=10^9$ and did not find a number $n$ with
the desired property. My conjecture is that there is no such number.
Can anyone prove or disprove this conjecture ?

Comment: Put $n=12$. $\sigma(12)=16$. Hence $\sigma(n)-n=4$, which is a proper divisor of $12$.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan No, $\sigma(12)=28$

Comment: @user26486- yes I'm sorry I forgot to add $12$ itself! Haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such $n$ such that $\sigma(n)-n$ is a proper divisor of $n$, except for prime numbers, for which it is trivial (as you stated).
Assume $n$ is not prime, and let $m$ be its biggest divisor (not necessarily a prime). Then $n=m\cdot p$ for some prime $p$. If $m=p$, then $n=p^2$ and $\sigma(n)-n=p+1\nmid p^2$. If $m\neq p$, then $\sigma(n)-n> m+p> m$, so $\sigma(n)-n$ is larger than any proper divisor of $n$, and can't be any of them.

Comment: One little detail is missing, the case $p=q$, but this implies $n=p^2$, with a prime $p$, for which we have $\sigma(n)-n=p+1$, which is not a divisor of $p^2$.

Comment: But beside this, an impressive proof!

Comment: I have greatly edited your answer to make it more clear and more rigorous and shorter. If you don't like it, then tell me.

Comment: @Peter: Does this question (and the corresponding answer) have a bearing on the [Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-24/NNTDM-24-3-062-067.pdf) on odd perfect numbers?